# NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/script/ScriptEngine

Tags: java, elasticsearch, noclassdeffounderror, scriptengine

i am new to Elasticsearch.
my project is gradle. using those dependencies;

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport', version: '6.5.0'

springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE' , Java Version1.8
```

My project was build by intellij and is running. (gradle build has done)

My Problem is that I want to run my project on terminal so I get `gradle bootRun` on terminal but I got this Error `NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/script/ScriptEngine`

Comment: hm, the dependency should work. Did you disable transitive dependencies somehow in your config?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving to version `6.5.3` because it supports JDK11, but more important thing is to use `RestHighLevelClient` instead of using `TransportClient`. According to documentation in version 7 `TransportClient` is deprecated. At version 8 it will be removed from the codebase.

So if you choose `RestHighLevelClient` you should have longer support.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.5.3'
}
```

Comment: That is **not** true! It will be deprecated in version 7 and removed in version 8...

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem. We have to deal usage of version between spring-data-elasticsearch and elasticsearch-client

```
spring data elasticsearch   elasticsearch
3.2.x                       6.5.0
3.1.x                       6.2.2 (I used)
3.0.x                       5.5.0
2.1.x                       2.4.0
2.0.x                       2.2.0
1.3.x                       1.5.2
Spring Boot Version (x) Spring Data ESearch Version (y) ESearch Version (z)
x <= 1.3.5              y <= 1.3.4                      z <= 1.7.2*
x >= 1.4.x              2.0.0 <=y < 5.0.0**             2.0.0 <= z < 5.0.0**
```